# Java Inheritance Primes Homework

Tags: java, inheritance, primes, instantiation

I have a multiphase homework due soon and my I'm on my last leg of it, but I'm very confused by it. The first assignment has me instantiating different Primes that all are dependent on each other and are all effected together no matter which one I refer to. The second part that I'm having trouble with is making it instantiable so that each Prime is effect independently and doing so by making a second class to show that they are independent.

My first class is this:

```
package project1;

public class Prime {
  //Part 2: Primes
  //Place your methods in here
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Prime p = new Prime();
        Prime p2 = new Prime();
        p.getPrime();
        p2.getPrime();
        Prime.getPrime();
        p.reset();
        p2.getPrime();
        p2.sumPrimes(4);
        p2.getPrime();
        p.getPrime();
    }

    static int num = 0;
    static int count = 0;

    public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
        if (p <= 1){
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < p; i++) {
            if (p % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int getPrime() {
        while (Prime.isPrime(num) == false) {
            num ++;
        }
        if (Prime.isPrime(num) == true) {
            System.out.println(num);
            num ++;
            return num;
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static void reset() {
        num = 0;
    }

    public static int reset(int n) {
        num = n;
        while (Prime.isPrime(num) == false) {
            num ++;
        }
        if (Prime.isPrime(num) == true) {
            return num;
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static int sumPrimes(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n > count) {
            while (Prime.isPrime(num) == false) {
                num ++;
            }
            if (Prime.isPrime(num) == true) {
                sum += num;
                count ++;
                num ++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        return num;
    }
}
```

I know it's not the prettiest code, but I'm a Java beginner. I only need to take this and make it so p and p2 are two separate variables by using instantiation and a new class called PrimeTest that has a main method that shows their independent. Anyone have any tips or examples I can look at?

Comment: Do you know what `static` means? I suggest you go and read about that. Basically, every occurrence of `static` (except the one in `public static void main`) should be removed from this code.

Comment: I'm very aware of static and what it does, but we are following a template that makes it so we have to use static variables and methods so that the two Primes are tied together and then we need to work around that using instantiation.

Comment: There is no way to work around it, other than to remove `static`. Static variables are, by definition, shared between all instances.

Comment: Well there-in lies the problem, then. So I can rid myself of the static variables and methods, but how exactly would I work in a second class that proves the two are instantiated separately?